# how to add average column and grand totals row in COBOL output file

Tags: cobol

My issue is that I am a beginner in cobol and because I do not understand the order of things quite well I am unable to recieve the correct output for my COBOL program. The output file is a .rpt file in that will show up in the bin debug folder of a COBOL program if you are using visual studio 2015. It may work in 2022 but we are not permitted to use that version. My goal is to have a row of averages added to the right side of the output file, as well as a grand totals row at the bottom with a total for at-bats, hits-in and average total. Currently, my computations display 0s, and my averages do not line up along the right hand side like the CORRECT output. SEQ file is listed below the code, this goes into the bin debug folder.

```
       IDENTIFICATION DIVISION.
       PROGRAM-ID. BASEBALL-2.
      * 
      ******************************************************************
      *
      *    This program reads a file containing population data about 
      *    U.S. cities.  It then changes the order of the fields and   
      *    writes a report showing this information.
      *
      ******************************************************************
       ENVIRONMENT DIVISION.
       INPUT-OUTPUT SECTION.
       FILE-CONTROL.

           SELECT BASEBALL-FILE-IN
               ASSIGN TO 'BASEBALL-2.SEQ'
               ORGANIZATION IS LINE SEQUENTIAL.
     
           SELECT BASEBALL-FILE-OUT
               ASSIGN TO 'BASEBALL-2.RPT'
               ORGANIZATION IS LINE SEQUENTIAL.

       DATA DIVISION.
       FILE SECTION.

       FD  BASEBALL-FILE-IN.
       01  BASEBALL-RECORD-IN.
           05  NAME-IN                 PIC X(18).
           05  FILLER                  PIC XX.
           05  LEAGUE-IN               PIC X(2).
           05  FILLER                  PIC XX.
           05  TEAM-IN                 PIC 9(3).
           05  FILLER                  PIC XX.
           05  AT-BATS-IN              PIC 9(3).
           05  FILLER                  PIC XX.
           05  HITS-IN                 PIC 9(3).
     
       FD  BASEBALL-FILE-OUT.
       01  BASEBALL-RECORD-OUT           PIC X(80).

       WORKING-STORAGE SECTION.
       01  ARE-THERE-MORE-RECORDS      PIC X(3)  VALUE 'YES'.
       01  LINES-PRINTED               PIC 99    VALUE ZERO.
       01  PAGE-NUMBER                 PIC 99    VALUE ZERO.
       01  WS-AVERAGE-AMOUNT          PIC 99    VALUE ZERO.
       01  WS-GRAND-TOTAL-BATS         PIC 99    VALUE ZERO.
       01  WS-GRAND-TOTAL-HITS         PIC 99    VALUE ZERO.
       01  WS-GRAND-TTL-AVG-AMT     PIC 99    VALUE ZERO.

       01  CURRENT-DATE.
           05  YEAR-X                  PIC XX.
           05  MONTH-X                 PIC XX.
           05  DAY-X                   PIC XX.
      

       01  HEADING-LINE-1.
           05                          PIC X(23) VALUE SPACES.
           05                          PIC X(27)
               VALUE 'BASEBALL PLAYER STATISTICS'.
           05                          PIC X(5) VALUE SPACES.
           05  HL-1-DATE.
               10  HL-1-MONTH          PIC XX.
               10                      PIC X     VALUE '/'.
               10  HL-1-DAY            PIC XX.
               10                      PIC X     VALUE '/'.
               10  HL-1-YEAR           PIC XX.
           05                          PIC X(3)  VALUE SPACES.
           05                          PIC X(5)  VALUE 'PAGE'.
           05  HL-1-PAGE-NUMBER        PIC Z9.

       01  HEADING-LINE-2.
           05                          PIC X(9)  VALUE 'LEAGUE'.
           05                          PIC XX VALUE SPACES.
           05                          PIC X(9)  VALUE 'TEAM'.
           05                          PIC XX VALUE SPACES.
           05                          PIC X(19)  VALUE 'NAME'.
           05                          PIC XX  VALUE SPACES.
           05                          PIC XX(13) VALUE 'HITS-IN'.
           05                          PIC XX VALUE SPACES.
           05                          PIC XX(13) VALUE 'AT-BATS'.
           05                          PIC XX VALUE SPACES.
           05                          PIC XX(10) VALUE 'AVERAGE'.
       


    

       01  DETAIL-LINE.
           05  DL-LEAGUE               PIC X(9).
           05                          PIC XX  VALUE SPACES
           05  DL-TEAM                 PIC X(9).
           05                          PIC XX  VALUE SPACES.
           05  DL-NAME                 PIC X(19).
           05                          PIC XX  VALUE SPACES.
           05  DL-HITS-IN              PIC 999.
           05                          PIC XX  VALUE SPACES.
.          05  DL-AT-BATS              PIC 999.
           05                          PIC XX  VALUE SPACES.
           05  DL-AVERAGE              PIC .999.
           05                          PIC XX  VALUE SPACES.

       01  TOTAL-LINE.
           05                                  PIC X(20)
               VALUE 'TOTAL'.
           05                                  PIC X(15) VALUE SPACES.
           05  TL-GRAND-TOTAL-HITS-AMOUNT            PIC 999.
           05                                  PIC X(10) VALUE SPACES.
           05  TL-GRAND-TOTAL-BATS-AMOUNT            PIC 999.
           05                                  PIC X(10).
           05  TL-GRAND-TOTAL-AVERAGE-AMOUNT         PIC 999.

       PROCEDURE DIVISION.
       100-MAIN.
           OPEN INPUT BASEBALL-FILE-IN
           OPEN OUTPUT BASEBALL-FILE-OUT

      *    Get the Current Date From The System
           ACCEPT CURRENT-DATE FROM DATE
           MOVE MONTH-X TO HL-1-MONTH
           MOVE DAY-X TO HL-1-DAY
           MOVE YEAR-X TO HL-1-YEAR
           PERFORM 300-WRITE-HEADINGS

           PERFORM UNTIL ARE-THERE-MORE-RECORDS = 'NO '
               READ BASEBALL-FILE-IN
                   AT END
                       MOVE 'NO ' TO ARE-THERE-MORE-RECORDS
                   NOT AT END
                       PERFORM 200-PROCESS-ONE-RECORD 
               END-READ
           END-PERFORM

           CLOSE BASEBALL-FILE-IN
           CLOSE BASEBALL-FILE-OUT
           STOP RUN.

       200-PROCESS-ONE-RECORD.
           IF LINES-PRINTED >= 57
               PERFORM 300-WRITE-HEADINGS
           END-IF
   
           COMPUTE WS-AVERAGE-AMOUNT ROUNDED = DL-AT-BATS / DL-HITS-IN
           MOVE NAME-IN TO DL-NAME
           MOVE LEAGUE-IN TO DL-LEAGUE     
           MOVE TEAM-IN TO DL-TEAM  
           MOVE AT-BATS-IN TO DL-AT-BATS
           MOVE HITS-IN TO DL-HITS-IN     
           MOVE DETAIL-LINE TO BASEBALL-RECORD-OUT
           WRITE BASEBALL-RECORD-OUT
               AFTER ADVANCING 2 LINES
           ADD 2 TO LINES-PRINTED.
       COMPUTE WS-GRAND-TOTAL-BATS = WS-GRAND-TOTAL-BATS + DL-AT-BATS
           COMPUTE WS-GRAND-TOTAL-HITS = WS-GRAND-TOTAL-HITS + DL-HITS-IN
       COMPUTE WS-GRAND-TTL-AVG-AMT = WS-GRAND-TTL-AVG-AMT + WS-AVERAGE-AMOUNT
           MOVE WS-GRAND-TOTAL-HITS TO TL-GRAND-TOTAL-HITS-AMOUNT
       MOVE WS-GRAND-TOTAL-BATS TO TL-GRAND-TOTAL-BATS-AMOUNT
       MOVE WS-GRAND-TTL-AVG-AMT TO TL-GRAND-TOTAL-AVERAGE-AMOUNT

       300-WRITE-HEADINGS.
           ADD 1 TO PAGE-NUMBER
           MOVE PAGE-NUMBER TO HL-1-PAGE-NUMBER
           MOVE HEADING-LINE-1 TO BASEBALL-RECORD-OUT
           WRITE BASEBALL-RECORD-OUT
               AFTER ADVANCING PAGE
           MOVE HEADING-LINE-2 TO BASEBALL-RECORD-OUT
           WRITE BASEBALL-RECORD-OUT
               AFTER ADVANCING 2
           MOVE 3 TO LINES-PRINTED.
```

```
Votto               NL CIN   354 121
McCutchen           NL PIT   569 190
Posey               NL SF    510 169
Frandsen            NL PHI   169 056
Lucroy              NL MIL   299 098
Ruiz                NL PHI   351 114
Molina              NL STL   487 156
Braun               NL MIL   572 182
Young               NL COL   174 055
Pierre              NL PHI   383 120
Ruggiano            NL MIA   288 090
Pacheco             NL COL   449 138
Wright              NL NYM   560 172
Craig               NL STL   447 137
Prado               NL ATL   599 183
Scutaro             NL SF    600 183
Werth               NL WSH   276 084
Kemp                NL LAD   378 115
Gonzalez            NL COL   518 157
Bloomquist          NL ARI   324 098
Cruz                NL LAD   255 077
Hill                NL ARI   578 174
Jay                 NL STL   422 127
Fowler              NL COL   454 136
Nelson              NL COL   324 097
Carpenter           NL STL   284 085
Ramirez             NL MIL   551 164
Desmond             NL WSH   489 145
Freese              NL STL   490 145
Tejada              NL NYM   433 128
Jones               NL ATL   370 109
Solano              NL MIA   258 076
Holliday            NL STL   582 171
Johnson             NL ATL   259 076
LeMahieu            NL COL   208 061
Denorfia            NL SD    324 095
Montero             NL ARI   468 137
Altuve              NL HOU   561 164
Murphy              NL NYM   544 159
Colvin              NL COL   396 115
Castillo            NL CHC   155 045
Pagan               NL SF    583 169
Bernadina           NL WSH   221 064
Dobbs               NL MIA   311 090
Aoki                NL MIL   491 142
Rutledge            NL COL   243 070
Sandoval            NL SF    375 108
Goldschmidt         NL ARI   497 143
Reyes               NL MIA   616 177
Tulowitzki          NL COL   181 052
Morse               NL WSH   383 110
Infante             NL MIA   328 094
Zimmerman           NL WSH   554 158
Ethier              NL LAD   531 151
Johnson             NL ARI   476 135
Rizzo               NL CHC   314 089
Stanton             NL MIA   427 121
Headley             NL SD    579 164
Phillips            NL CIN   558 158
Castro              NL CHC   619 175
Hanigan             NL CIN   308 087
Forsythe            NL SD    298 084
Walker              NL PIT   472 132
Schumaker           NL STL   265 074
```

I tried adding average and grand average variables to the working storage and creating a new working storage for grand totals, as well as adding the arithmatic down in the processing areas of the program. Shown below is the correct layout, simplified into one page.

```
BASEBALL PLAYER STATISTICS         10/09/12    PAGE  3
LEAGUE    TEAM      NAME                  HITS         AT BATS      AVERAGE
NL        WSH       Zimmerman              158             554         .285
NL        LAD       Ethier                 151             531         .284
NL        ARI       Johnson                135             476         .284
NL        CHC       Rizzo                   89             314         .283
NL        MIA       Stanton                121             427         .283
NL        SD        Headley                164             579         .283
NL        CIN       Phillips               158             558         .283
NL        CHC       Castro                 175             619         .283
NL        CIN       Hanigan                 87             308         .282
NL        SD        Forsythe                84             298         .282
NL        PIT       Walker                 132             472         .280
NL        STL       Schumaker               74             265         .279
TOTALS                                   7,851          26,342         .298
```

Comment: **The record layout for `BASEBALL-RECORD-IN` is incorrect.** This program could not have worked. The are two missing separator periods. There is no calculation or output for `DL-AVERAGE`. The calculation for `WS-AVERAGE-AMOUNT` is incorrect. The fields for `WS-GRAND-TOTAL-BATS` and `WS-GRAND-TOTAL-HITS`, at `PIC 99`, are too small.

Comment: Thank you for your comment! and yes, you're right, the code did not run in this state.

Answer (score 1):

First item - This is simply a matter of STYLE, and PERSONAL PREFERENCE - I prefer to line all of the 'PIC' keywords up so they are easier to read, and if possible use `X(yy)` for pictures (`X` being type and `yy` being length, including leading zero if necessary). This avoids such items as `XX(13)` and includes `X(01)` as a picture, not `X`. Obviously, this is not universally applicable - `Z(03)9(01)` for instance.

Second item - `DL-HITS-IN` should have `PIC Z(02)9(01)` since you wish to display a 3-character field that is numeric with the leading zeroes replaced by spaces. (Other fields similarly).

Third item - in `200-`, you are computing `WS-AVERAGE-AMOUNT` from the report-line fields, but you haven't set those fields up yet - that's done in the following lines. You should move this computation to AFTER the `DL-` fields are established. You haven't `move`d the calculated amount to `DL-AVERAGE`. It should be possible to calculate `DL-AVERAGE` directly (compute DL-AVERAGE...) without using the intermediate storage `WS-AVERAGE-AMOUNT` - and the calculation should be made on the raw data fields `AT-BATS-IN` & `HITS-IN`, not the formatted fields `DL-`

Fourth item - Whereas `WS-GRAND-TOTAL-BATS` & `...-HITS` should be calculated within `200-`, there is no point in setting items `TL-` within `200-` as the `TL-` figures will be overwritten for every input record.

Fifth item - Having processed all of the records, you are simply closing the output file, without writing the totals line. This should be done as another paragraph `400-write-footer` which should move the grand totals to the appropriate fields and calculate `TL-GRAND-TOTAL-AVERAGE-AMOUNT` by dividing the two `WS` fields. Having constructed the totals line, it needs to be written out to the report file. You also need to look at the `PIC`s on the total line. Try `Z(03),Z(02)9` for the total and `.9(03)` for the average as before.

Then there's the matter of **<kbd>.</kbd>**. From a compatibility POV, I would write the entire job in COBOL-74 since (1) I'm used to it and (2) some organisations have not "moved on" from that version. No doubt an academic institution would require that you use the "latest and greatest". My version would simply have each statement terminated by a `.` but whether and where those should go (or are optional) may be compiler-dependent.

Comment: Thank you @Magoo for all of your info! It was very helpful! My code is running and looking normal, except I did not update the PICs yet. I will post the updated code soon. Thanks again.